# Unable to use terminal

Tags: command-line, zsh

[image: system info]

The terminal colour changes automatically, but I am not able to use the terminal for executing the commands.  I have used `pywal` and the code used is:

```
while true
do
wal -q -i /home/amithkumar/Pictures
sleep 1
done
```

If I remove these lines, the terminal runs smoothly.
But I want these lines to remain in my `.zshrc` file, so how can I fix this?

The only way I can use the terminal is by entering into root directory, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then to home, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then it stops changing the terminal command.

[image: screenshot of temrinal]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> don't work.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Jammy Jellyfish

Comment: The code you have add'ed runs an infinite loop (while true ...) and will block the terminal for any interactive use. What do you want to achieve with the added code ? Maybe there are an other way ?